# Taking expectation of higher moments using original distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, moments

If we want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$, we know this is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X(x) dx$.

When we want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$ (for, say, positive integer $n$), we also do this with respect to the pdf of $X$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f_X(x) dx$. Why can we do this? Is $Y = X^n$ not its own random variable, and so should the expectation not be calculated with respect to the pdf of $Y$ (which could be derived using e.g. some transformation rule), something like $\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y f_Y(y) dy$?

Comment: Google the "law of the unconscious statistician" . Basically this result is just a change of variables formula for integrals under image measures.

Comment: For applications and other accounts of LOTUS, see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=lotus%20-logistic%20score%3a2&searchOn=3).